# How to retain the values of a dynamically generated dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm building a webapp using the codeigniter framework. I have a series of 4 dropdown fields in my form that are each dependant on the last so I use JQuery to populate them after the user selects an option.

This works well until the user submits and the submit fails for whatever reason. When this happens the user must fill out the form again because the dropdown values are only filled by user input.

I can store the users selections in the session. but how should I go about re-building the dropdowns with their correct options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it store item of this dropdown either in `hiddenfield` or in `cookies` before postbacking page and after postback get data again from `hiddenfield` or `cookies` and restore it.

when you are restoring from hiddenfield or cookie just check it contains data or not if not  than populate it as you are populating at page load.

Check this solution : [Javascript Cookie Library with jQuery bindings and JSON support](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/)

---

You can also use : [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

```
// Save data to a the current session's store 
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John");  
 // Access some stored data 
alert( "username = " + sessionStorage.getItem("username"));
```

The sessionStorage object is most useful for hanging on to temporary data that should be saved and restored if the browser is accidentally refreshed.

Comment: The OP is not concerned about where to store the data, but *how* to repopulate the form fields.

Comment: Yes, but how? The data is stored as a string. Which data format should be used? How to parse that data format into an object structure, and how to fill the dropdown fields based on that object? That is what OP is asking here.

Comment: OK, let's say we store the data as a JSON string. Now, how do we repopulate the form fields based on that JSON string. Does jQuery provide a built-in method for that, or do we have to manually iterate the properties of the parsed JSON structure?

Comment: Thanks Šime, you're correct in your assumptions. One idea I had was to  have two separate ways of populating the dropdowns, the first for when the user is interacting with the form, the second handles populating them on submit failure.